# PhantomJSDriver element click

Tags: c#, webdriver, phantomjs

with chromedriver, everything is working like a charm. When I try PhantomJSDriver, it clicks the login button but not the continue button. The program finds the element but the click doesn't work.

```
web.FindElement(By.XPath(DS_login.lBtn)).Click();` <- works

if (Class_doExist("visual-label-main") // it is there and tries to click
 { 
     FindElement(By.ClassName("visual-label-main")).Click(); //<- this click doesnt work
 }
```

Error :

> _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but worked by using XPath..